# Дружественный метод шаблонных наследуемых классов

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

### Имеются два шаблонных наследника классов и дружественная функция:

Файл header.h

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class _list : public list<T> {
public:
    friend void fill_int(int);
};

template <typename T>
class _vector : public vector<T> {
public:
    friend void fill_int(int);
};

template <typename T>
void fill_int(int num) {
    while (num) {
        this->push_back(rand() % 128);
        num--;
    }
}
```

Файл main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    _list<int> lint;
    lint.fill_int(7); // <<<<<<< here
    return 0;
}
```

Функция как дружественная вынесена для того, чтобы быть доступной в обоих классах. Работать отказывается. Говорит:

> Ошибка    C2039   fill_int: не является членом "_list"

Comment: Имейте в виду, что использование идентификаторов начинающихся с подчеркивания в глобальном пространстве имен в С++ нелегально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И правильно говорит - вы говорите, что у вас где-то там есть функция, которой разрешено доступ к внутренностям вашего класса. Не более того.

Раз уж вы хотите использовать ее в разных классах - то вам нужно передавать ей объект класса, что-то вроде

```
template <typename T>
void fill_int(T& container, int num) {
    while (num) {
        container.push_back(rand() % 128);
        num--;
    }
}
```

И использовать не как `lint.fill_int(7);`, а как `fill_int(lint,7);`.

И делать ее дружественной совсем ни к чему - потому что `push_back` - открытый член (надеюсь, вы его не делали закрытым/защищенным?).

И еще - зачем у вас ваши список и вектор - шаблоны?

```
template <typename T>
class _list : public list<T> {
public:
    friend void fill_int(int);
};
```

Раз уж вы `push_back(int)` делаете, и `int` явно прописываете - то что у вас такого шаблонного в ваших контейнерах?...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Цель была - добавить пару своих функций к библиотечным классам vector и list через наследование, чтобы они, как и другие методы, были доступны через точку. Передача экземпляра класса как параметр - уже не то.. Подобное мне уже удалось реализовать, сделав эту функцию членом класса _list и унаследовав _vector от vector и _list. Все для того, чтобы код функции был доступен для редактирования только в одном из классов-потомков.

Comment: Простите уж, но наследовать вектор от списка? Это же совершенно разные вещи. Как по мне - не стоит возможность вызова "через точку" бездумного наследования.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять свои функции такого рода вам не понадобится,  поскольку стандартная библиотека имеет достаточно альгоритмов для контейнеров. Например ваша функция делает то же, что и:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), num, []() { return rand() % 128})
```

Comment: 1. namespace "std" не содержит члена "generate_n" 2. что такое v?

Comment: А кто говорил про пространство имен ? Стандартная библиотека и пространство имен std совершенно разные понятия.   Нужно подключать соответствующий заголовочный файл  стандартной библиотеки, чтобы иметь  std::generate7 Там v это имя контейнерного обьекта(вектора). Фиктивное имя.

Comment: подключайте  #include <algorithm>